# how to use vlookup command in this situation

Tags: excel, excel-2007

the sytax of vlookup

```
vlookup(value we are looking for, Data range, index, exact/aprrox. match)
```

i.e `vlookup(A1,B1:E3,1,false)`
the vlookup will the first column for looking up our desired value which is in cell A1.
but if with the same data range i want it to search my value "A1" in the 3rd column and it should return me the value in the first column.

Example to clearify my question

```
     A      B      c     D    E
1    22    area    3     4    5
2          length  2     22   2
3          height  4     32   7
```

in the above data I want excel to search A1 which is "22" in column D and return the value opposite to it in column B which is "length"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=INDEX(B1:B3,MATCH(A1,D1:D3,0))
```

In responce to comment, using `Index` `Match` in a horizontal fasion:

Suppose your data is like this

```
     A      B       C       D
1    22     area    length  height
2           3       2       4
3           4       22      32
4           5       2       7
```

To get the same result as per your original data, use

```
=INDEX(B1:D1,MATCH(A1,B3:D3,0))
```

Comment: Dear This Index Coammand is Working only for Columns and if we have to deal with Rows then how to deal with that 1, kindly Answar.

Comment: Refer to the Excel Help, which fully explains the use of `Index`

Comment: i have checked the excel help and already using Index-match in place of vlookup but the problem now is with Hlookup how to replace its limitation of processing only 1st row. and if possible tell me way we may use index-match for Hlookup too. Thanks